# how to use ngx-admin backend

Tags: angular9, nebular, ngx-admin

I started working with angular based template ngx-admin.
I want to know how to link the frontend template to backend.
and is there an altenative to ready to use bundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, Akevo charges for the backend. You need to create your own backend. It's better if you go for the mean stack. That would be perfect for Angular.

If you want to know how to start, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toRmWFzB6-E&t=323s) is the link of the youtube tutorial which will help you how to start implementing backend and connect it to frontend. This is just for your understanding. You need to create your backend for your ngx-admin frontend.

This tutorial will also help you understand how to work with login and registration